# How did the terrorists get into Canada unnoticed?

Tags: plot-explanation, die-hard-with-a-vengeance

I just watched the movie *Die Hard with a Vengeance,* and I feel like there’s a missing piece of the puzzle.

Near the end of the movie, we learn that the terrorists are staying near a truck stop in Canada called *Nord des Lignes*, but my question is, **how did they manage to bring themselves and some $13 billion worth of gold past the US-Canadian border unnoticed?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Prior to 2009, [there was no passport requirement to enter Canada from the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_entry_into_Canada_by_land#:%7E:text=Beginning%20in%202009%2C%20U.S.%20citizens,Global%20Entry%20or). Before this time, while many larger entries had checkpoints, there were plenty of ways to get around them.

This movie [was released in 1995](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112864/) and is approximately contemporary. With a little bit of planning, it would have been fairly easy for a stream of trucks carrying anything to move from the US to Canada.

Comment: This. I transited that border as a kid once in the late 1970's to visit Niagra Falls, and the only "check" I remember was asking if we had fruit. Never had a passport, and nobody got out of the car. All the talk in the US about border security is largely just about the US *southern* border, which shows you the whole topic is more about race and politics than actual security. The US Canada border is 5.5 **thousand** miles long, and historically nobody has cared much about "controlling" it.

Comment: The link is not that accurate for the movie. It's mostly "*US citizens*" who are kind of free and won't be bothered. As the terrorists (which I'm not BTW :-)), I'm a foreigner, and we *need* a passport to cross the border. I **did** show passport and visa to go to Niagara Falls (both sides).

Comment: @OldPadawan hence, _many larger entries had checkpoints,_ like Niagra Falls. The second I picked randomly from [a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Canada%E2%80%93United_States_border_crossings) tells [a very different story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derby_Line%E2%80%93Stanstead_Border_Crossing#:~:text=using%20any%20of%20the%20roads). Also, the border crossing was not shown in the movie and there is no way of knowing if, "the Germans," showed US passports.

Comment: @T.E.D. - how in the world does that show that it's "more about race and politics than actual security"? Are canadians smuggling literal tonnes of cocaine across the border? Do you also think it's racism when Finaland is more concerned with its border towards Russia instead of the one towards Sweden? What kind of nonsense even is that?

Comment: Back in those days a US citizen could cross the border with just a driver's license. Driver's licenses back then did not have the indications they have today (Real ID and other stuff) that would necessarily make it clear who is a citizen.

Comment: *Die Hard with a Vengeance* was 1995; not much after (and pre-2001) I was touring with a group of cyclists who, riding through the Eastern Townships, spent a day and a half on the U.S. side to ride part of Lake Champlain.  The U.S. side (a building with a covered area for a couple of vehicles to pull up) was far more built up than the Canadian side (basically a shack), but we had _way_ more difficulty communicating the concept that we were travelling _by bicycle_ to the U.S. border guards than we had with ID.  Pretty much anything from a recognized jurisdiction with a photo was fine.

Comment: Many US-Canada border crossings even today have a sign that says "please head over to X in order to clear customs", often many km away.  There is a US-Canada border crossing that is the line down the middle of a road, with houses on both sides.  Prior to 9/11, crossing the border as a non-citizen resident would be trivial with no passports, and any ID check was more perfunctory than an ID check in a bar.  During this period of nearly no security, Canada shipped megatonnes of illegal (in USA) cannabis to the USA.

Comment: @T.E.D. I don't want to derail this discussion overmuch, but the general arguments about Mexico is people coming over the border "raping and robbing" and "taking our jobs", which leads to the common joke that this implies that people have a funny idea of what jobs are being taken. There's also some concern over drugs being smuggled. As far as I know, Canada doesn't have as prominent of a problem of drugs and undocumented workers crossing the border, so it's less a political hot potato.

Comment: Crossing the border as an individual or family is a very different thing than bringing a commercial vehicle across the border.  Yeah, it's easy to cross into Canada.  I crossed on bikes with a friend who only had a photocopy of an expired passport 5-10 years ago and they Canadian officer didn't really care.  Coming back was a different matter.  But if you come across with a truck full of something, they would have some questions.  There are taxes to consider and I'm pretty sure Canadians don't want people importing garbage/toxic waste.

Comment: @Yakk Oh how I wish the Canadians drove on the left hand side of the road.

Comment: @JimmyJames "But if you come across with a truck full of something, they would have some questions." post-9/11 I drove a friend to his new job in northern USA and back again in a cube van.  They never looked in the back on either direction.  Now, coming back it would have been obvious anything we carried was light (from how the truck suspension was hanging), but still: the border is very porous, and millions of tonnes of goods cross it every day, and no they aren't searching most of it.

Comment: @Yakk Were you driving a commercial vehicle?  Did you go through a bus/truck lane?

Comment: @JimmyJames it is correct that a station wagon with mom, dad and the kids is different from 14 dump trucks full of gold bullion. _However,_ the point is that the situation was _very different_ in 1995 than it is now or recently. _Back then,_ there were places you could cross without any checkpoint (or lanes, etc.) at all, on the honor system. It doesn't seem to me to be a stretch that some already-criminals would exploit a loose hole after dark to make a rich getaway.

Comment: @StephanSamuel I can see them maybe sneaking across the border at some informal crossing, maybe.  But the idea that Canadian customs just waved 14 dump-trucks through is laughable, even in 1995. My father-in-law once crossed to do a seminar in Canada.  He made the mistake of admitting he was being paid (something like $30CA) and they made him pre-pay taxes on it at the border. This was well before 1995. They also are really worried about bringing stuff over without paying duty.  They would want to know what was in the trucks.

Comment: @JimmyJames So, you'd either (a) find an insecure crossing with nobody guarding it, (b) have a pre-bribed crossing with someone on your payroll that waves you through, (c) have pseudo-fraudulent paperwork to carry garbage over the border and look legitimate.  This isn't super challenging at the scale of what the bad guys do in the movie.

Comment: @Yakk Sure but it's not explained or discussed, right?  All these comments about how you could cross with your family so easy are completely irrelevant.  And given the trouble people go through (even back then) to smuggle things like cigarettes and booze on boats at night (sometimes crashing into each other and dying in the process) don't suggest to me that it's super simple to smuggle large quantities of contraband into Canada.

Comment: I mean, how much hand holding do you really need?  It is very plausible.  The border was porous, and still is.  I guess you want them to spell out every single little step of every detail like they do on much American media?  Sigh.

Comment: @JimmyJames They shoot 2 NYPD officers and a detective at the beginning of the movie in order to steal the gold and countless other people, some law enforcement, along the way. If they were asked for anything for entry, at night, in a desolate place on the Canadian border, why wouldn't they just shoot whoever asked them? That is, **if** they were even asked, and there's a very mixed bag of peoples' experiences with the likelihood of that.

Answer (score 17):

> how did they manage to bring themselves and some $13 billion worth of gold past the US-Canadian border unnoticed?

It's never explained, but we can take two things into account:

1. the line between the 2 countries isn't *that* sealed a border.
2. the aspirin bottle comes from the Canadian part of the border.

First, as a foreigner, when living in the US, I was able to cross the Canadian/US border twice in a day without my passport (I had forgotten it at the hotel). It was 1992. It seems to be much harder nowadays.

Second, the "Germans" probably came to the US from Canada, where they bought the aspirin. They chose a place where trucks going back and forth are so common that controls are less than ideal, more chances to go unoticed. It's not the last stop at the border going to Tijuana.

So it seems pretty easy for the terrorists to have customs papers ready just in case. Trucks have been stolen a while ago, giving time for some proper preparation. So people working and their trucks, in an area full of trucks. If you want to hide something, just put it where it's natural for it to be.

Comment: "the line between the 2 countries isn't that sealed a border" is a bit of an understatement, haha.  The majority of the nearly 9,000 km (over 5,500 mile) border is completely open and unpatrolled, although thermal cameras and such are in use since 9/11.  There are only a couple hundred official crossings, and a lot of them are very low-tech and unserious, especially compared to busy ones like the Peace Bridge.

Comment: When and where did you enter Canada without a passport?

Comment: @user1271772:  From the USA (visa from Europe), 1992. I went to Canada and back to the USA on the same day.

Comment: I suggest that you add to your answer that you were able to do that in 1992, so that no one thinks that this is still possible post-9/11. The movie that was mentioned in the question was also pre-9/11, so your anecdote is relevant to the answer, but might be misleading to anyone that doesn't know that the Canada/USA border is much more strict than you described.

Answer (score 5):

In the [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/452193), based on a slightly earlier version of the screenplay, there's a slight time-jump of about a week between the scene with the aspirin bottle and the showdown. During that time the terrorists were able to melt down the bullion into something a little less conspicuous.

> A long pause followed. McClane guessed that Simon was wondering how much he knew. He pulled out a small statue of the Empire State Building, the kind that all the New York souvenir stores carried, and scuffed it against the edge of the table. When he turned it over, the bottom of the statue gleamed with gold.
>
> "The gold wasn't on that ship. You drove it where? North?" He'd had plenty of time to think about this. He gave Simon his best guess. "Canada?"
>
> "Congratulations. Nova Scotia," Simon said tersely.
>
> "Melted it into trinkets and shipped it out."

You can see this version of events in the alternative ending.

Comment: I really have a problem with "*[official (or not) novelisations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novelization#Film)*", because of what they do with some version of the script, so my POV might be biased. But in the movie, they use [dump trucks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dump_truck), a type of vehicule used to transport materials such as dirt, gravel, or demolition waste. That's why they can go unoticed in the tunnel. But they surely wouldn't be if they were loaded with goods such as small statues/souvenirs.

Comment: @OldPadawan - In the book they've had time to transfer them over to a more appropriate vehicle. In the film they evidently wanted more Action-packed ending, and damn the continuity errors

Comment: So plagiarised directly from The Lavender Hill Mob.

Comment: @BangBang - There isn't a single scene in this movie that isn't cribbed directly from a better film.